# error: The argument type 'MaterialPageRoute' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<Map>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter and this code is straight from the teacher. I know that flutter changing all the time and this may be why it is not running. anyways here it is:

```
class Klimatic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KlimaticState createState() => new _KlimaticState();
}

class _KlimaticState extends State<Klimatic> {

  String _cityEntered;

  Future _goToNextScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    Map results = await Navigator
        .of(context)
        .push(new MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new ChangeCity();
    }));

    if ( results != null && results.containsKey('enter')) {
       _cityEntered = results['enter'];

//      debugPrint("From First screen" + results['enter'].toString());


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the current Flutter reject the parameter type of `dynamic` for `MaterialPageRoute`.

You need to change the following code:

```
Map results = await Navigator
    .of(context)
    .push(new MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return new ChangeCity();
}));
```

to

```
Map results = await Navigator.of(context)
   .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeCity();
      })
   );
```

As you can see from the above changes, you don't need the `dynamic` keyword. And there is no need for `new` keyword anymore because it's optional now.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowledge of the exact API details, it looks like you are expecting a type of `Route<Map>`, but you're creating a `Route<dynamic>` (or `MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>`). I'm assuming you could try:

```
new MaterialPageRoute<Map>(...)
```

... instead.